# $_POST not working with apache rewrite. using index.php as controller

Tags: php, apache, post, controller, url-rewriting

THE PROBLEM: I can't get any POST variables anywhere. Not even at the top of index.php. Is this because of the apache rewrite rule?

Here is my .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

This makes everything go to index.php
I'm using this as my controller file
So everything goes through index.php first

What other apache rules do i need to get the $_POST data to my index.php?

here is the basic form:

```
<form action="/signup" name="form_name" method="POST" id=""> 
<input type="text" name="field1" value="" /> 
<input type="text" name="field2" value="" /> 
<input type="submit" name="" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure this is the problem but you should do RewriteRule . index.php [L]

Comment: Rewrite shouldn't affect post variables.

Comment: i just added [L] but still no $_POST data to my index.php. All form data will process as it should without the apache rules, which is why I was under the impression that the $_POST data does not make it through the rewrite process. But thank you anyhow.

Comment: Could you add the code which you use to `POST` to index.php?

Comment: I added form info above

Comment: Johni is correct! rewrite does not affect the post variables. The issue i'm having is related to my includes and changing the header info based on certain conditions. I'm getting the following error: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent . I'll need to revise my question or start a new one.